# Magento 1.9.3.1 customer_flowpassword doesn't exist

Tags: customer, password-recovery

Got an error with "reset password" in 1.9.3.1?

Run this sql to create the missing database table "customer_flowpassword". Magento maybe did not create the table after your update to 1.9.3.1.

Make sure to correct the "'"

Comment: I have the same problem, by running the sql below, does that solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, but make sure to correct the ""

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_flowpassword` (
  `flowpassword_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Flow password Id',
  `ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User IP',
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Requested email for change',
  `requested_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Requested date for change',
  PRIMARY KEY (`flowpassword_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_FLOWPASSWORD_EMAIL` (`email`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_FLOWPASSWORD_IP` (`ip`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER_FLOWPASSWORD_REQUESTED_DATE` (`requested_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Customer flow password' AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```